# Perl github api not returning anything

Tags: perl, api, github, github-api

I'm trying to use the Perl [`Net::GitHub::V3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aGitHub%3a%3aV3) module and I can't seem to get any results.  My code is below along with what I get in return.  Any suggestions?

The Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Data::Dumper;
use Net::GitHub;
use Net::GitHub::V3;

my $github = Net::GitHub->new( api_url =>'http://my.domain.com/api/v3/legacy/');
my $search = $github->search;
my %data = $search->repos("hello-world");
print Dumper(\$data{repositories})
```

The response (no errors):

```
Not Found at git_repos.xml line 9.
```

Comment: That does not return what I want.  It prints out the $search variable, which is the object that I search through.  It's required in the API.

Comment: A dubious looking module, nothing for error checking in the docs.  Start with use strict and warnings. Then check if $github or $search are getting defined.